# Symbian S60 Qt calendar application

Tags: qt, symbian, s60

Using Qt I want to store some calendar events on Symbian S60. However these calendar events should in no way be synchronized with a server, for example when a user synchronizes his calendar with an exchange server over bluetooth my calendar should be untouched. Is there any way to store my calendar events into a private calendar, not the default calendar? How can this be done in Qt?

Answer (score 0):

Check out QOrganizerManager. This should allow you to select another calendar than default